# LINQ to SQL created an extra model file in our ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I am learning MVC and in one of our ASP.NET MVC 4 app I see some models created via LINQ to SQL. Under Models folder, I see a file `Models\myProjectDataModel.dbml\ myProjectDataModel1.designer.cs`, and another file `Models\myProjectDataModel.designer.cs`.
In the first file name please note the "1" at the end of the file name. I used the Windiff from Windows 7 to compare these two files and their content are exactly the same. I am confused as to how the first file (with "1" at the end) was created? Can one of these files be deleted without effecting the app?
Can someone please explain?

Comment: Delete all of them and regenerate the model.

Comment: To play save, just exclude those files from your project (right click > exclude from project in visual studio's solution explorer) then try to rebuild the project. If build failed, you can include them back to project and think of other solution rather than delete them right away.

Comment: Per an advice from har07, I excluded the file Models\myProjectDataModel.designer.cs from the project. After rebuilt, the project is working ok without any errors "so far". If there are other possible solutions, I would like to know.